# Change Currency for in app purchase (internal testing)

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

My app is in internal testing . The issue is that it shows INR (my country currency) in app purchase  I want to change it

Answer (score 0):

The currency is linked to the store you're purchasing in.

To change it, you have to:

- uninstall your app
- change your Play Store from India to whatever you want
- reinstall your app

Comment: How to change Play Store country ?